# 1 server for each language in http://www.domain.com/<lang>/

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, load-balancing

Is is possible to set up IIS (or a load balancer of some kind) so that each URL of the form...

```
http://www.domain.com/en/
http://www.domain.com/fr/
http://www.domain.com/es/
etc...
```

... is handled by a different server? There should be no HTTP redirection, i.e. the URL stays as it is in the user's browser.

Comment: That doesn't sound very load-balanced to me...

Comment: Well, the goal isn't actually load-balancing. It's more isolation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can tell IIS to proxy requests for particular URL subsets to other servers using the URL Rewrite module and [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting)  module.  Some additional documentation is available at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/740/application-request-routing-module/

Comment: +1 ARR is the IIS/Windows solution but if licensing costs or load is an issue, HAProxy on Linux also works very well.

Comment: If licencing costs were an issue, you wouldn't be using Windows in the first place.

Comment: The OP wanted options (IIS or a load balancer of some kind). I gave him more than the IIS specific one you offered.